Scope of an entry added to a c++ set?
Let's say I have a globally scoped set defined as follows:
std::set<Person> people;

I also have a function where I create an instance of the class Person, and add it to the set as follows:
void addEntry() {
    Person p1("kosh", 55);
    people.emplace(p1);
}

The way I understand it, a copy of the object will be created (I can see the copy constructor getting called) and added to the set. Once this function terminates, p1 goes out of scope. But, what is the scope of the copy that is added to the set? Is that determined by the scope of the set?
EDIT 1:
A follow-up question:
In such a scenario, is is better to just create p1 in the heap, instead of the stack, and store the pointer in the set?

Please don't ask multiple questions in one post.  If you have any more followup questions, post them separately.

you almost never want to store pointers in standard containers. You need pointers to store polymorphic objects, and in some other cases, but not here.

Whether something is "better" always depends on your needs. Sets don't even move their elements around, so some of the reasons to store pointers (expensive moves for some reason, or wanting to keep their this pointers constant) don't apply. Still, std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<ItemBase>> children; -- here, we refer to a base class that can be different actual classes. std::unordered_map<PackageID, std::shared_ptr<const LicenseInfo>> licenses; -- here, the objects might persist beyond their presence in the map.

"scope" applies to variables. For values, the question should be about "lifetime".

Lifetime vs scope
The lifetime of an object is the stretch of time during the program's execution in which the object is alive and can be accessed.
The scope is the places in the code from which such accesses can be made. See also:
Scope vs. Lifetime of Variable
Lifetime of the object in the set
You're calling the set's emplace() method, with a (reference to) a local variable.
What does emplace(t) do? Its function is rather uniform across different collections:
emplace(t): Construct a new object of within the container, as a copy of the object t.
(I've simplified things bit, e.g. w.r.t. move semantics)
So, you don't actually put t inside the container. You create a different object; and containers, like std::set(), are implemented so that the lifetime of the created element will be effectively the same as the container's.
Notes:

Remy Lebeau's answer is correct, I just wanted to focus on the method used.
Note that std::set is intended for ordered elements; the mathematical notion of a set is better captured by std::unordered_set.

The follow-up question: Should you use pointers?

is is better to just create p1 in the heap, instead of the stack, and store the pointer in the set?

Why would that be better? ... I presume you would say this avoid creating two Person's.
Well, actually, try something different: Don't create p1 at all; just emplace() using the arguments to the constructor of the Person class, and then there will never be any object other than the one created within the set. So, only a single Person instance is created and then used.


But, what is the scope of the copy that is added to the set? Is that determined by the scope of the set?

Yes.  The copied object is stored inside the set object, and will be destroyed when the set is cleared or destroyed.  Unless you erase() the entry for the copy beforehand.

In such a scenario, is is better to just create p1 in the heap, instead of the stack, and store the pointer in the set?

While that would avoid a copy, you would then have to deal with the overhead of a dynamic allocation and managing the lifetime of the object which is being pointed at.  Also, storing pointers in a set kind of defeats the purpose of using a set anyway, since it would not be able to compare the objects by default, it would only compare the pointers. You would have to provide the set with a custom comparitor that dereferences the pointers.
A simpler option would be to just not pass an object into emplace() for it to be copied.  You can pass in the desired Person constructor parameters directly to emplace(), and it will create the Person object internally for you, eg:
void addEntry() {
    people.emplace("kosh", 55);
}

